# How to disable backspace behaviour in EditText Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, long-press

For example I have following string in EditText:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat

The normal behaviour is, when user long press on backspace button in virtual keyboard, the system will delete each word directly, for example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat

becomes

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat

Can I prevent such behaviour to happen in my app?

I have tried to observe `onKeyDown`, `onKeyUp`, `onKeyLongPress` and `onTextChanged`, `afterTextChanged`, `beforeTextChanged`, but doesn't find something that I can use to prevent such behaviour.

Comment: Why is it that you want to avoid this?  Anytime you want to change something so fundamental in the OS you need really think it through.

Comment: There is no specific reason actually, I only want the long press behaviour same with short press in backspace key.

Comment: Yeah, if there is no really compelling reason then you shouldn't do it.  Changing a fundamental paradigm of the OS is always going to result in a bad experience for the user.

Comment: This isn't necessarily the OS, but rather the IME (soft keyboard). Android allows you to install 3rd-party IMEs, and any of them could potentially handle those key presses differently (which you would have no control over at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding this would only confuse the user, its a bad idea.  But here's how keyboard work in Android-  they decide what buttons are shown and what they do in response to user input.  There's no way to override this.  If you don't like this behavior, I suggest you find a keyboard that works the way you want.

Overriding onKeyXXX won't work because those are for physical buttons, and won't be generated by onscreen keyboards.

If you *had* to override this, you'd need to implement a TextWatcher and edit the sequence s in afterTextChanged.  You'd need to look for cases where the new text is smaller than the old text by more than 1 character and if so replace the text with the old text minus 1 character.  Please note that this may, depending on how the keyboard and Android sequence events, break any keyboard with autocorrect on or any keyboard that uses completion text.

In other words-  don't do it, its going to be way more trouble than its worth and will break for most users.

Comment: Ok. I totally agree with you, CaseyB, and Karakuri. I will redesign usability of my app.